# JQuery hover backroundColor

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am building a set of social media links in a Rails 5 app. When I hover over the links container div, I want its background color to turn blue. (You cannot use CSS :hover for backgroundColor fyi)

Something in Rails 5 must be preventing this from working. I have used literally this exact code in another app, and it worked great. I can't figure out what is happening. Here is my html:

```
<div id="facebook">
    <%= icon("facebook", id: 'facebook_icon') %> 
</div>
```

Here is the relevant portion of my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function (){

$('#facebook').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': '#404a87'},400);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': '#393939'},400);
    }
);
});
```

Other JavaScript functions in this file work. I can't figure out what could be happening. Help!

Comment: I am want to change the div, not the icon. Thanks for the thought though

Comment: Why not use `.css('background-color','#404a87')` ? Does it have to be the js backgroundColor? `#facebook:hover{background-color:#404a87; -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s; transition: background-color 0.4s} `

Comment: Try background-color instead of backgroundColor. Yes, I know that backgroundColor "should" work - but try it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work but try:

```
$('#facebook').on("mouseover", function(){..}
```

instead of using .hover